# Make R use '_' instead of '.' while performing outer join

Tags: r

I'm performing an outer join using following syntax:

```
final <- merge(x=A, y=B, b=c('id'='id', 'time'='time'), all=TRUE)
```

It runs fine, but for variables with similar names it uses.x/y which is useful but the variables' names now cannot be used in SQL and other stat software.

Therefore, is there a way where I can specify R to use '_' instead of '.' in naming new variables when performing the out join?

Comment: Maybe you need to change the argument `suffixes` in `?merge`? Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so folks can test their solutions?

Comment: `merge(x=A, y=B, b=c('id', 'time'), all=TRUE, suffixes = c('_x', '_y'))`

Comment: In SQL surround the variable name with double quotes or square brackets.  Using SQLite via sqldf try this: `library(sqldf); sqldf('select "Sepal.Length", [Petal.Length] from iris' )`

Answer (score 0):

merge(x=A, y=B, b=c('id', 'time'), all=TRUE, suffixes = c('_x', '_y'))

The answer from @onyambu helped. Thanks, @onyambu.